# Where's a ByteArray's data stored?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript

I'm using URLStream to download a big file and save locally on a mobile app. To do this, i need to store the downloaded bytes on a ByteArray:

```
private function handleStreamProgress(event : ProgressEvent) : void {
  if ( urlStream.bytesAvailable == 0 ) return;
  if ( urlStream.connected ) {
    urlStream.readBytes(byteArray, byteArray.length);
    fileStream.writeBytes(byteArray, bytesOffset);
    bytesOffset = byteArray.length;
  } 
}
```

Are these bytes from the downloaded file stored in Memory? (Profiler doesn't show any excessive memory consumption, though...)

Should I clean the byteArray after each sequence of bytes is stored?

Answer (score 0):

The data is stored in memory unless you explicitly push the data to disk.

I'm not sure what you mean by *clean the byteArray*. The `ByteArray` as a whole contains the bytes which make up the data. You can certainly break the array apart and merge it back at a point in time but the data itself must remain somewhere for your downloaded data to be representative of what it actually is.

Comment: At each dispatched progress event I take the recently loaded bytes and write to disk, so I could clean the ByteArray after. The problem in doing so is that the byteArray clean method takes some time, and calling it over and over again can be worst than not calling at all.

What's really interesting is that when running a profiler, the app doesn't show a significant increase in the swf memory consumption even loading a 100Mb file with the urlStream.

Comment: @cassiozen If you are writing to disk and clearing, you are only going to be consuming a given block of your file within memory, so it wouldn't be expected that you wold see the full 100MB consumed during your handler, nor should the memory footprint increase that significantly. It is obviously dependent on the inbound size of the stream.